# two urls - one website - how to show only one to google

Tags: seo

There are two URLs for one Website.

One is f.e. http://www.exmaple.com/6/jklabradors
This one is used to edit the Website in a CMS
and should NOT show up in Google.

The other one is: http://www.example.org
This one is the "right" one, which should show up in Google.

What do i have to do, that only the second domain www.example.org is listed in Goolge and NOT the other one?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `palimpalem` domain to be listed in google, create a `robots.txt` file, disallowing it to be indexed, with something like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Yes, i want palimpalem.com to be indexed in general. Some users have own domains, others not. When a user has an own domain, i don't want to index Google the palimpalem Domain. Only his "own" domain. Otherwise i want to index the palimpalem url of the user.

Comment: In that case, you should do a `301` redirect (permanently moved) from that particular url.

Comment: i have tried that, but the problem is that in this case several tools from the cms doesn't work, because the cms needs the palimpalem.com/... url. Thats why i asked the question, if there is a way to prevent google from indexing it, but withour doing a permanent redirect. Thanks for your ideas and effort in any case.

Comment: I was thinking of that particular URL. Not the entire domain. You can also create a robots entry for the individual urls you want to exclude.

Comment: May be i didn't explain it well: www.palimpalem.com/999/username/index.html is the website of the user. www.userdomain.com is the domain of the user. I put now the canonical link <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.userdomain.de" /> in the index.html in www.palimpalem.com/999/username/index.html and hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Google has also stated that you can use the rel="canonical" meta tag on the version of the page you want Google to see.  The search engine will notice the similarities among pages and index the one that has that tag in it.

Here it is, straight from the horse's mouth: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Other than this, I would use Robots.txt and leave it off your Sitemap.xml page.

Comment: rel canonical is the best solution in this case. The advantage being that links to the non-canonical URL will count toward the pagerank of the canonical one. Simply robots'ing, redirecting, or 'noindexing' the page will cause any value that page accumulates to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

This is an easy way that google won't index this part. 
information:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

```
noindex: prevents the page from being indexed
nofollow: prevents the Googlebot from following links from this page
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: that would prevent Google from indexing the website. But thats not what i want. I just want that Google doesn't index  http://www.palimpalem.com/6/jklabradors which aponts to the same website like http://www.javer-keleb.com. You understand?